# The difference between comparably and comparatively

Tags: differences

I'm currently studying for my proficiency exam and I just came across a vocabulary problem that I need some help with:

In one of the exam questions the correct solution to a 'fill-in-the-gap'-exercise was the following:

'..., but it is in fact a habit which is COMPARATIVELY easy to acquire.'

Before looking at the solutions I had the word 'comparably' instead of 'comparatively' in the gap. I tried to look at some sample phrases using 'comparably' to get a feel for the difference between the two words [here](http://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/sentences-with-the-word/comparably.html) but I can't seem to get the hang of it.

If anybody could shine a light on the use of these two words, that'd be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definitions will reveal the difference.

**Comparably**

> in a similar way or to a similar degree.

**Comparatively**

> to a moderate degree as compared to something else; relatively.

Source: Oxford Dictionaries

...**but** it is in fact a habit which is similarly(**comparably**) easy to acquire

It is contradictory to use 'but'(which introduces a view that is **different** from what was stated in the first part of the sentence) and comparably(**similarly**) in the same fragment.

... **but** it is in fact a habit which is relatively(**comparatively**) easy to acquire

Since a comparison is being made here, it is absolutely correct to use 'comparatively'. *Comparatively* and *but* correspond with each other in terms of meaning.

*Comparatively* as well as *comparably*, convey the meaning of comparison(estimate of the similarities or dissimilarities between two things or people) but it must be noted that *comparably* talks only about the similarities whereas *comparatively* takes both similarities and dissimilarities into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

"Comparatively +adj" is a variant of "relatively +adj". The BNC shows roughly 8000 incients for relatively and 1000 incidently for comparatively.

http://bnc.bl.uk/saraWeb.php?qy=comparatively&mysubmit=Go

http://bnc.bl.uk/saraWeb.php?qy=relatively&mysubmit=Go